# Backup android sqlite database to google drive

Tags: android, database, backup, google-drive-android-api

I'm developing an android app and I want to do an autobackup of the database to google drive when you close the app, but I don't have any clue of how to do that. Do you have any tutorial or something so I can learn how to do this backup.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation of Auto-Backup feature
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup.html#EnablingAutoBackup

Comment: Link answers the question, but you could have put more effort on answering. Reported.